# <apex:commandbutton> not working

Tags: salesforce

I am working on  button.

My component code is as follows.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!sendAction}" 
value="SEND" styleClass="Button" rerender="messageId" immediate="true"/>

<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!showmsg}" id="messageId">
            <apex:outputtext value="{!outputMessage}" style="color:red;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"/>
            <br />    
        </apex:outputpanel>
```

My controller code is as follows.

```
public PageReference sendAction()
{ 
    showmsg=true;                     
    outputMessage='working';             
     return null;                        
 }
```

But my action method sendAction is not getting called. 
When I open my page containing  in new window , function is getting called. But in same window it is not getting called.

Any help is really appreciate.

Comment: Did you specify `controller="Your-Controller-Name"` or `extension="Your-Controller-Extension-Name"` on your page tag?

Comment: yes..i have added controller in <apex:component> tag

Comment: @dip did you try my suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

If, as Matthew already hinted your controller is refered by your page or component I believe it may be caused by the showmsg variable.

If the messageId outputpanel is not renderd because showMsg is initially false, it will also not rerender, and thereby not display your message. If i'm right, the following would make more sense, and fix your problem.

```
<apex:outputpanel  id="messageId">
        <apex:outputtext rendered="{!showmsg}" value="{!outputMessage}" style="color:red;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"/>
        <br />    
    </apex:outputpanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approaches in the case when your`<apex:commandButton>` or `<apex:commandLink>` doesn't seem to call the apex controller method.

1. Try setting the attribute `immediate = true` for these two. That works in some cases.
2. Try calling the apex controller method using the `<apex:actionFunction>`.
3. If somehow you're still unable to call the apex controller method using the `<apex:actionFunction>`, refer to [this](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/11/apexactionfunction-is-not-calling-apex.html) link.